# Does Synchronization protects file integrity when accessing through java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency

I have created a Java Web Application using Spring Boot. I am using a file for storage instead of DataBase (It is the requirement). I have implemented Synchronization concept to protect the file from multiple writes at same time.

My Sample code is a follows:

Read File:

```
public class ReadFile{

 public Json readFile() { 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
               Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("sample.json")));
        //Check for null json file
        example = gson.fromJson(br, Json.class);
        br.close();
}

}
```

Parent Class:

```
public class ParentClass extends HttpServlet{

 public ReadFile file= new ReadFile();
public Json example = file.readFile();

public synchronized void writeToFile(Json example){
//code for writing to file
}
}

}
```

Child Class1:

```
public ChildClass1 extends ParentClass {

public void doGet(){
    //code to read example object
}

public synchronized saveContentstoFile(){
    //do some changes to example object
    writeToFile(example);
}

}
```

Child Class2:

```
public ChildClass2 extends ParentClass {

public void doGet(){
    //code to read example object
}

public synchronized saveContentstoFile(){
    //do some changes to example object
    writeToFile(example);
}

}
```

In all the above classes, I am using "example" as a shared object holding file contents between all 3 classes.

I haven't seen any file corruption issues with limited testing. I am new to use this concept. Can anyone comment if it is the correct way or if there are any unseen issues?

If not, Which is the best implementation to protect file from getting corrupted ?

Comment: You only need to synchronize `writeToFile()` and `readFile()`, but you need to synchronize them on the same object, and you aren't. Why are you wrapping a `BufferedReader` in a `BufferedReader`?

Comment: *You only need to synchronize writeToFile() and readFile()* In order to synchronize across methods you need to Synchronize on a common Object

Comment: So it's a miracle that you haven't seen any file corruption. Better testing required next time.

Comment: @EJP I am using example object as common object which is inherited from parent class to all child classes..wrapping is done based on suggestion from PMD static code analysis tool..Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: No. If you have instances of `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2` you have *two* objects, both synchronized on themselves and not against each other. `Files.newBufferedReader` already returns a `BufferedReader`: you don't need another one.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for your reply. Can I use Semaphore instead of syncronized keyword where ever I access shared object. Does it solve the issue? @EJP

Comment: Just use an existing solution - [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html)! You obviously don't know enough about either concurrency or file based databases - JSON is a bad choice as you'd need to rewrite the whole file to make even a minor change.

Comment: @BoristheSpider No. `FileLock` will not work across threads in the same process. See the Javadoc.

Comment: @EJP my bad, I should read these things more carefully. Out of interest, do you know of a way of controlling exclusive access within a JVM? I suppose using a plain old `Lock` would appropriate?

Comment: @hanish Yes, you can use a `Semaphore`, but that still gives you the same problem of ensuring it is the *same* `Semaphore`. The simplest solution would be to synchronize on a static object, for example `Parent.class`.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for your suggestion and can you please give me an example of your solution if possible

Comment: I don’t get it. All of these objects are writing the same contents to the same file or what? Why?

Comment: @Holger Yes. All the child objects are created using a file and being writtien to the same file once the required manipulation is done

Comment: Perhaps the difference is in the “required manipulation” you didn’t show in the question, as writing *the same content* over and over again makes no sense. On the other hand, writing different contents, just to let the next object overwrite it, makes no sense either…